# getting 500 internal server error HTACCESS

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website that's running this htaccess without any problem.

I have uploaded my site on my other host and Now I'm getting 500 internal server Error.
This is my htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
# Don't allow any pages to be framed - Defends against CSRF stock CSRF attacks
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/* play.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^pr-([0-9]+)\/.*?$ index.php?p=dis_add&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user_Account/chats/([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=fchat&id=$1
RewriteRule ^فراموشی_رمز_عبور$ index.php?p=forgetPassword
RewriteRule ^user_Account$ index.php?p=userAccount [L]
RewriteRule ^logout$ index.php?p=logout [L]
RewriteRule ^login$ index.php?p=login [L]
RewriteRule ^newAdd$ index.php?p=newAdd [L]
RewriteRule ^newAdd/([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=newAdd&catId=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^user_Account/ea/([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=userAccount&what=editadd&id=$1 
RewriteRule ^user_Account/(.*?)$ index.php?p=userAccount&what=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ad-([0-9]+)/.*?$ index.php?p=dis_add&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^app index.php?p=info&pid=10 
RewriteRule ^stores/([0-9]+)/.*? index.php?p=displayStore&Idot;=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*?)/.*?$ index.php?p=info&pid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^adds/([0-9]+)/.*?/([0-9]+)/.*?/category-([0-9]+)/.*?/subcat-([0-9]+)/.*?$ index.php?p=display_adds&cityId=$2&subCatId=$4
RewriteRule ^adds/([0-9]+)/.*?/([0-9]+)/.*?/category-([0-9]+)/.*?$ index.php?p=display_adds&cityId=$2&catId=$3

RewriteRule ^adds/([0-9]+)/.*?/([0-9]+)/.*?/subcat-([0-9]+)/.*?$ index.php?p=display_adds&cityId=$2&subCatId=$3
RewriteRule ^adds/([0-9]+)/.*?/subcat-([0-9]+)/.*?$ index.php?p=display_adds&stateId=$1&subCatId=$2


RewriteRule ^adds/category-([0-9]+)/.*?/subcat-([0-9]+)/.*?/$ index.php?p=display_adds&subCatId=$2
RewriteRule ^adds/category-([0-9]+)/.*?$ index.php?p=display_adds&catId=$1

RewriteRule ^adds/([0-9]+)/.*?/category-([0-9]+)/.*?$ index.php?p=display_adds&stateId=$1&catId=$2

RewriteRule ^adds/$ index.php?p=display_adds&all=true
RewriteRule ^adds/([0-9]+)/.*?/([0-9]+)/.*?$ index.php?p=display_adds&cityId=$2
RewriteRule ^adds/([0-9]+)/.*?/category/([0-9]+)/.*?$ index.php?p=display_adds&stateId=$1&catId=$2

RewriteRule ^adds/([0-9]+)/.*?/([0-9]+)/.*?/category/([0-9]+)/.*?$ index.php?p=display_adds&cityId=$1&catId=$2
RewriteRule ^adds/([0-9]+)/.*?$ index.php?p=display_adds&stateId=$1


RewriteRule ^blog$ index.php?p=tuts



RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/.*?$ index.php?p=display_adds&catId=$1 


RewriteRule ^conrimPayment$ index.php?p=conrimPayment

RewriteRule ^n([0-9]+)/.*?$ index.php?p=Disnews&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/.*?$ index.php?p=DisBlog&id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^c([0-9]+)/.*?$ index.php?p=adCat&catid=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^category/.*?/([0-9]+) index.php?p=adCat&catid=$1   
RewriteRule ^category/.*?/.*?/([0-9]+) index.php?p=adCat&catid=$1  

RewriteRule ^loc/.*?/([0-9]+) index.php?p=loc&ostanId=$1   
RewriteRule ^loc/.*?/.*?/([0-9]+) index.php?p=loc&cityId=$1  

RewriteRule ^vije\/pr-([0-9]+)\/.*?$ index.php?p=dis_add&id=$1&sp=1&special=0 [L]
RewriteRule ^vije$ index.php?sp=1 [L]

RewriteRule ^mosabeghe\/pr-([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=dis_addMosabeghe&id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^ekhtesasi$ index.php?sp=1&special=1 [L]

RewriteRule ^عمومی$ index.php?p=adds&kind=omu [L]
RewriteRule ^مزایده$ index.php?p=adds&kind=moz [L]
RewriteRule ^استخدام$ index.php?p=adds&kind=est [L]


RewriteRule ^خبرها$ index.php?p=news

Options -Indexes
```

Why Am I getting 500 internal server error.I'm running this on my other host And it's running properly.What's wrong with this?

Comment: What does your apache error log show?

Answer (score 0):

I just disabled saving with DOM and the problem is gone .